# CSS font-family: Use Apostrophe quotes or Quotation marks to surround names with spaces?

Tags: css, syntax, fonts, double-quotes

I think I understand why quotes are used in CSS around certain font family names; Mainly if the name contains white space. But I see different people use apostrophes OR quotation marks for quotes. Does it matter?

I want to make sure that if a slider plugin on my site is searching for 'Open Sans', but the main font family on my theme is defined as "Open Sans", then the page and the slider aren't searching for 2 different things and wasting resources, if that's even a thing that would happen.

**i.e.;**

```
.someslidercaption {
    font-family : 'Open Sans', sans-serif; 
    }
```

**vs.:**

```
.someelement {
    font-family : "Open Sans", sans-serif; 
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure those are equivalent. I'm not sure you even need quotes at all, for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, since the [string constant syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#strings) just defines: “Strings can either be written with double quotes or with single quotes.” There is no statement that would make any difference according to which delimiter is used.

It would not even matter if you omitted the delimiters. Contrary popular belief, `font-family : Open Sans, sans-serif` works fine, too. Although delimiters are recommended when the value contains spaces (as per the [`font-family` section](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#propdef-font-family) in CSS 2.1), they are required only in rather anomalous cases (e.g., when a font family name contains two consecutive spaces).

The context may affect your choice in this respect. In the example `<BODY STYLE="font-family: '21st Century', fantasy">` (in the CSS 2.1 spec), with a style sheet embedded in an HTML attribute enclosed in double quotes, single quotes are more convenient on the CSS side (since doubles would have to be escaped at the HTML level).

Comment: Generally, quotes are required in cases where the family name cannot be sufficiently represented as one or more valid CSS identifiers. Granted you could just escape away all of the special characters then, but you must really, really, really hate quotes to find yourself doing such things.

Comment: My personal rule of thumb is to always use quotes (either single or double, but consistent across the project) for font names, even the ones without spaces, like `font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;`. It also clearly differenciate between font name and font group.